# Length contraction at an Angle

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames

[image]

If the ship arrives at the slit at $45^\circ$ and the slit projection onto the ship is narrower than the needed then the ship won't make through. However, if it travels at 90% of the speed of light there should be length contraction, so would it pass in this case?

Comment: You can think in either the lab frame or the ship frame. This is perhaps easier to visualize in the lab frame. The length of the ship will contract, but the width will not. If the projection of the ship onto the slit is too wide, it will be too wide at 90% the speed of light.

Comment: But is there also some contraction in width because in the frame paralel to the slit the ship is going let say roughly 60% of c? (dimmension component). There is a lot of possibility that I am wrong but I am asking because I am a little bit confused.

Answer (score 1):

The dashed line through the center of the ship helps you think about this in the lab frame. It shows you all the places the nose will be.

Add dashed lines for the edges. They show where the edges will be. They will not get closer together if the ship travels at high speed. If they cross the slit, the ship will be too wide. Speed will not help.

You can also do the same thing in the ship frame. You have a dashed line through the center of the slit showing where the center will be. Add dashed lines to the edges of the slit. If those lines cross the ship, the slit it too narrow.

The angle is at an angle. But the lines show the component of the width perpendicular to the motion. This component does not change.

The component parallel to the motion will be contracted. If you draw that, you will see the slit changes angle. This is one of the counter intuitive effects of relativity. It is much the same as seeing a sphere at rest, but a flattened elliptical cross section at speed.

Comment: If we immagine the ship as a ball going horizontally at 60% of c it should look like an elipsoid with precise orientation but now start a vertical acceleration of it so it arrives at 60% of c in the vertical dimension so the absolute velocity is around 90% of c.The shrinking of the lenght in the vertical dimension must also take place because if not it doesn't make sense as there is relativistic motion in that spatial dimension component too. Should mathematics work in the same way for  component velocities as for the absolute velocity?

Answer (score -1):

Length contraction at near light speed, or Lorentz contraction, is effected by several other phenomena due to general relativity.  But as I understand it, it appears to any observer that the object would contract in the direction its traveling in by (1-v²/c²)½  v= relative velocity of the moving object, c= speed of light in a vacuum.
       From what I understand though, it  only appears to an observer to contract, so say it was a ship with a passenger, it wouldn't contract from their frame. Im going to say I dont think it works in you question...... But maybe this will help out.
  https://physicsworld.com/a/the-invisibility-of-length%E2%80%AFcontraction/

Comment: I don't think length contraction (or any other phenomenon as long as the velocity is constant), is affected by general relativity. Also, the phrase "appears to an observer to contract" is false. It indeed physically gets smaller. It's not an optical effect.

Comment: I did say 'general relativity' When I meant special relativity, my mistake. But frame of reference matters with anything (outside the quantum realm) maybe 'appears to the observer' was bad phasing though without giving more detail.